# Java: threading divided into blocks array - executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am creating a program to calculate values of two arrays in steps of simulation (they are initialized from the beginning, I did not put it here). I would like to do it with threads and ExecutorService. I divided arrays into blocks and I want values of these blocks to be calculated by threads, one block = one thread. These two arrays - X and Y - take values from each other (as you can see in run()), I want X to be calculated first and Y after that, so I made two separate runnables:

```
public static class CountX implements Runnable {
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private CountDownLatch cdl;
    public CountX(int s, int e, CountDownLatch c) {
        this.start = s;
        this.end = e;
        this.cdl = c;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = start + 1; i < end - 1; i++) {
            x[i] = x[i] - (y[i-1] - 2 * y[i] + y[i+1]) + y[i];
        }
        cdl.countDown();            
    }
}
```

And same for CountY. I would like to give to it the information where the start and end of value for every block is.

This is, in a short, how my main looks like and this is the main problem of mine:

```
int NN = 400; //length of X and Y
int threads = 8;
int block_size = (int) NN/threads;

final ExecutorService executor_X = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads); 
final ExecutorService executor_Y = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(threads);
    
CountX[] runnables_X = new CountX[threads];
CountY[] runnables_Y = new CountY[threads];

for (int r = 0; r < threads; r++) {
        runnables_X[r] = new CountX((r*block_size), ((r+1)*block_size), cdl); 
}
for (int r = 0; r < threads; r++) {
        runnables_Y[r] = new CountY((r*block_size), ((r+1)*block_size), cdl);
}


int sim_steps = 4000;
for(int m = 0; m < sim_steps; m++) {
    for (int e = 0; e < threads; e++) {
        executor_X.execute(runnables_X[e]);
    }
    for (int e = 0; e < threads; e++) {
        executor_Y.execute(runnables_Y[e]);
    }
}
executor_X.shutdown();
executor_Y.shutdown();
```

I get wrong values of arrays X and Y from this program, because I also did it without threads.
Is CountDownLatch necessary here? Am I supposed to do for loop of `runnables_X[r] = new CountX((r*block_size), ((r+1)*block_size), cdl);`  in every m (sim_step) loop? Or maybe I should use ExecutorService in a different way? I tried many options but the results are still wrong.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is one I probably wouldn't take for this task.

You can work with references and Runnables, but in your case a [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) might be the better choice. With a Callable, you just give it the array and let it calculate a partial value, if possible and await the `Futures`. For me, it's not really clear what you actually want to calculate though, thus I am taking a blind guess here.

You don't need a `CountDownLatch` nor two `ExecutorServices` - one EXS is enough.

If you really want to use a `Runnable` for this, you should implement some sort of synchronization, either with a concurrent list, Atomic variables, `volatile` or a lock.

Comment: I am calculating values of X and Y, which are in run() of runnables

Comment: That's a bit broad. You only shared your x-calculation which is somehow related to the values of y. When x depends on y to be calculated first, you should do the y calculation first, await the results and then calculate x. Also,  arrays are not thread safe.

Comment: y also depends on x in the same way as x depends on y. 
Thank you anyway! I will try to work with Callable here.